# (python) code to edit a text file using loop to delete some initial text of each line of the text file

Tags: python, text-files, edit

I wish to remove the beginning numbering of each line.

My file looks like this:

4. Logic Puzzle: A man has 53 socks in his drawer: 21 identical blue, 15 identical black, and 17 identical red. The lights are out and he is completely in the dark. How many socks must he take out to make 100 percent certain he has at least one pair of black socks?

Answer: 40 socks. If he takes out 38 socks (adding the two biggest amounts, 21 and 17), although it is very unlikely, it is possible they could all be blue and red. To make 100 percent certain that he also has a pair of black socks he must take out a further two socks.

5. Logic Puzzle: The day before two days after the day before tomorrow is Saturday. What day is it today?

Answer: Friday. The “day before tomorrow” is today; “the day before two days after” is really one day after. So if “one day after today is Saturday,” then it must be Friday.

(continues like this... with a logic puzzle and an answer.)

(source: https://parade.com/970343/parade/logic-puzzles/)

Comment: What have you tried so far?